# Find expectation for $x$

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

for $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}$, $x = 0,1,2,3,\dots$
Find $E(X)$

So far I have got to Summation infinity $x = 0$ to $x = \inf\{\frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)}\}$ 
How do you work out the summation? The answer they gave is infinity which doesnt make sense.

Comment: The sum "behaves like" $\sum \frac{n}{n^2}$, and we know the harmonic series diverges.  One can make this more formal in various ways, Limit Comparison, or noting that the denominator is $\le (n+n)(n+2n)$.

Comment: @Drhab Whoops, sorry.

Comment: Your discrete random variable $X$ has PDF $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)},$ for $x = 0, 1, \dots.$. You should be able to verify that $\sum_{x =0}^\infty f(x) = 1$. The sum of the first thousand terms is about 0.9990. However, $E(X)$ does not exist because the infinite series $\sum_{x =0}^\infty xf(x)$ diverges. Do you know how to check whether such an infinite series converges or diverges?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by $f(x)$ you mean the probability mass function of random variable $X$. The definition of the expectation in this discrete setting is $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty xf(x) = \sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)}$.

This partial fraction may be split as $\sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+1})$. The first and second terms sum up the same basic fractions starting at different limits and scales. Noting that $\sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty \frac{2}{x+2}= \sum \limits_{x=1}^\infty \frac{2}{x+1} = -2+\sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty \frac{2}{x+1}$, our overall expectation sum simplifies to $\mathbb{E}(X) = -2 + \sum_{x=0} \limits^\infty (\frac{2}{x+1} -\frac{1}{x+1})$.

This is nothing but $-2 + \sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x+1}$, and this series is well known to diverge, specifically to $+ \infty$. To see why, visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics).